# Como tirar duplicidade de valores de um ArrayList

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, genéricos

Gostaria de saber como posso separar os valores que apresenta duplicidade, um exemplo:

Tenho uma Variável `FormaPagto` definida como uma `ArrayList`,

Nessa Variável tenho 6 dados:

> 0 - Dinheiro 1 - Debito 2 - Debito 3 - Dinheiro 4 - Dinheiro 5 -
>   Cheque

O que quero fazer, separar os valores distintos, no caso pegar apenas o valores sem que eles se repitam, ficaria assim:

> 0 - Dinheiro 1 - Debito 2 - Cheque

Agrupando os valores deixando eles únicos, e se possível deixar em uma `ArrayList`.

Existe alguma função da própria `ArrayList`, que faça tal mágica? Ou o que me sugerem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro, nao se deve usar `ArrayList`.
Desde a introdução de *genéricos* em C# 2.0, recomenda-se a utilização da [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) genérica.

Com uma `List<T>`, pode-se usar a extensão [`Enumerable.Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx) para eliminar valores duplicados.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

var list = new List<String> {"Dinheiro", "Debito", "Debito", "Dinheiro", "Cheque"};
var distinct = list.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Eu cheguei a ler sobre essa função, pois meu projeto inteiro foi feito em ArrayList, gostaria de saber o pq não devo usa-la? Seria por ser limitado? Ou? 

E outro, esses valores que citei, virá de uma List(que seja List<T>).

Comment: Sim, `ArrayList` é limitado em vários aspectos. 1) não é genérica, e portanto todos os elementos são `object`, 2) sempre que se retira um elemento da lista, tem que ser feito o cast para o tipo correcto - casts levam a código que pode falhar em runtime, e portanto, a código com bugs, 3) não suporta as extensões LINQ para manipulação de dados. Recomendo **vivamente** a fazer refactoring do projecto, e a substituir todas as `ArrayList`s por `List<T>`s

Comment: Ah, e 4) como todos os elementos são `object`, uma `ArrayList` com value types (inteiros, doubles, booleans) vai fazer *boxing* de todos os elementos, e isso tem um impacto significativo na performance